# What causes this extremely strange Port Forward behaviour?

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding, nat

**The scenario**

Basically, for about 10 years I lived in a country where my ISP gave me a NAT'ed address on their end (MAN). So I couldn't port forward unless I paid. However that was not an option.

I have just moved to a new country however and the ISP here has much less customers. Checking my ARRIS router/modem shows that *the WAN ip is public!* I thought "finally, I can port forward".

But I was wrong:

**The problem**

Even with a new public WAN IP on the router, I observe some **strange behavior.**

- Checking canyouseeme.org with ANY PORT other than 80 (even forwarded) returns "CONNECTION REFUSED".
- Checking canyouseeme.org with PORT 80 returns "CONNECTION TIMED OUT".
- The router has "two" public IPs: *gateway IP* and *wan IP* I used WAN ip in my tests.
- I **CAN** ping the WAN IP (even from remote pinger, ping.eu). Positive result.

So I have a few questions:

*If all ports return "refused" but 80 returns "timed out", does that mean my ISP blocks port 80?*

*What's the difference between "gateway IP" and "wan IP"?*

*What could I do to solve this?*

Comment: Just because you can ping a website or an address does not mean any other traffic will be allowed.  An ISP can allow ICMP packets but deny anything else.  Hosting a server, on a residential connection, is often against the usage agreement with your ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer your question we need a little knowledge about the port forwarding.

To forward a port we need a **NAT** policy which will convert **TCP 80** traffic from public IP to private IP address and eventually private IP will be listing on **TCP 80** and will process data `(HTTP GET Request)`.

Connection timed out and Connection Refused means we do not have the port opened. ISP might have not blocked but your public IP should have the proper **NAT** rules and **allow access rules** to get this done.

Gateway IP is the one which is sitting on ISP end and WAN IP will sit on customer end. Both will be in the same subnet and will provide L2 connectivity between ISP to customer site.

Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Yes the thing is, in my post it says all ports except 80 say connection refused, however 80 shows timed out. What would that mean?

Comment: Connection refused means port is blocked / server not listening on those ports. Connection timed out is trying to get to server and TTL expired or timed out in-transit.

Comment: Yes, but WHY is port 80 timed out and others refused? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Is any service pointing to your WAN IP? (Have you opened any service for your WAN IP?)

Comment: I have. I forwarded it if that's what you're asking.

Comment: What is the port number you have opened and help me with the packet dump if available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37663/discussion-between-joseph-a-and-manjesh23).